# How do you lock slash commands for everyone?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Right now all my discord.js slash commands are usable by everyone but I want to lock some to being used only by admins. My code (in my index.js) is below but it's not doing anything because I can't figure out how to set everyone's perms to false as a base. Where am I going wrong?

````
const modperms = [
    {
        id: '123456789012345678',
        permissions: [{
            id: '123456789012345678',
            type: 'ROLE',
            permission: false,
        }],
    },
    {
        id: '123456789012345678',
        permissions: [{
            id: 'aroleid',
            type: 'ROLE',
            permission: true,
        }],
    }
];

client.guilds.cache.get('aguildid')?.commands.fetch('about').permissions.add({ modperms });```
````

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the official guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-command-permissions.html).

> If you set `defaultPermission: false` when creating a command, you can
> immediately disable it for everyone, including guild administrators
> and yourself.

And then enable it for a specific role

```js
const permissions = [
    {
        id: '123456789012345678',
        type: 'ROLE',
        permission: true,
    },
];

await command.permissions.add({ permissions });
```

Comment: Right but where do you add defaultPermission: false?

Comment: the same place where you add your name and description of your command in the slash command object (defaultPermission is an optional parameter)

Comment: How do I format that? I tried .defaultPermission(false) and a bunch of varients of that but none of them worked

Comment: You have to put it inside the object, so `{stuff: "stuff", defaultPermission: false, moreStuff: "stuff"}`